# Django using is_valid on a field where null=True

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

in my models.py, I have null=True for a specific field.

```
date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

I leave it blank and press submit. When I handle the POST request in views.py I print out request.POST and date equals "". How would I get is_valid to accept this as a null value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after reading through a few other posts, I found something that works (but I'm not sure if this is good practice or out-of-date)... anyways, I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723315/django-form-validation-based-on-whether-field-has-value). Here is the example that I used:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    #exclude etc as you wish

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    #init the form as usual
    super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    #then change the required status on the fields:
    self.fields['baz'].required = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Default is not a boolean field. Default is what you provide to set a default value for the column. Remove default and try to submit the form again.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#default

Comment: This didn't change anything

Comment: Then there's something else going on here, but my comment is still accurate, if not problem-solving :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `blank=True` to the field and that's all.

```
date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

The `blank` keyword argument targets to the form fields, as opposed to `null` which is db-related. You can read about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#blank